# Set Title with getSupportActionBar() after sliding thru Fragments doesn't work

Tags: android, android-fragments

I use 2 fragments. Let's say A & B

In my activity:

```
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
 getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
 getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
 getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Title A");
```

It works before sliding. Fragment 1 : Title Bar shows Title A.

In my fragment:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
 if (isVisibleToUser == true) {((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Title B");}
```

I slide to my fragment B, it works perfectly. Its title shows Title B.
Now, I go back to the Fragment A, the title stays the same instead showing Title A (it shows Title B instead Title A)

But it works if I trigger with the Home Button, I go back with the Home Button and Fragment A displays Title A.

Code :

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item)
{

    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {  


    case android.R.id.home:
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        int mycurrentpage = pager.getCurrentItem();
        if (mycurrentpage ==0){
            pager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
        }
        if (mycurrentpage ==1){
            pager.setCurrentItem(2, true);
        }
        if (mycurrentpage ==2){
            pager.setCurrentItem(3, true);
        }
        if (mycurrentpage ==3){
            pager.setCurrentItem(4, true);
        }
        if (mycurrentpage ==4){
            pager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Title A");
        }

        return true;
    }
.......
```

How can I make it work?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried to set the title in your fragment's `onResume()` instead of `setUserVisibleHint()`?

Comment: It doesn't work. Actually it's the same if I want to trigger a Toast.makeText from the activity page (fragment A). It triggers at launch then nothing after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not override setUserVisibleHint for this. This method is not suitable for doing stuff like this. Use a PageChangeListener

Comment: You were right. It works perfectly ! Thanks so much!